# Dynamically Choose a File Depending on Props

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to import a file dynamically based on props, or at least find a way to get a file based on props. Is there a way to do that?

```
import json from '../../data/yearly/CAN.json';
```

In this case I would want CAN.json to be this.props.country + '.json'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can..

What you're looking is called [Dynamic Imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports). You should only use it only when necessary though.

It works the same as importing statically, however when exporting a default module, you need to destructure first.

Example code of using it:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    async function importSelect() {
      const { default: data } = await import("./Testing");

      setData(data);
    }
    importSelect();
  }, []);
```

[Here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-christian-nmi0l?file=/src/App.js) sandbox link to check if data is loaded